# Magento 1 :Home page Same product show .this remove on this producrt

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento 1 home page only one product show 1 first product configurable and second product simple show problem only showing simple product get the home page work. and i have in home page only showing simple product please help this frind..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4yBSb.png)

Comment: So, you want to display the simple product on your homepage only?

Comment: yes. i want to home page only showing product simple

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 solutions for that:

- You can use the filter to get all simple product on the collection.
- You can check if/else on the loop when you print product. So, just display simple and ignore configurable product

Comment: $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection') ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', array('eq' => 'simple'))->addAttributeToSelect('*'); /*or just the attributes you need*/
foreach ($collection as $product) {
     //do something with $product
}

Comment: sorry friends i misunderstanding  only for configurable product show one product only showing simple so please simple product remove only

Comment: In this case, you change 'eq' => 'simple' to 'eq' => 'configurable'